# For a multi-threaded application why is it required to go for a synchronized implementation (if the requirement doesn't state that)

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, stringbuilder, stringbuffer

I have a very basic question. I have read that if we have a multi-threaded application then it is better to go with `StringBuffer`. But if we have a single thread application then it’s better to go with `StringBuilder`.
But isn't the whole point of having a multi-threaded application is that simultaneously all the threads can work on the same piece of code? Shouldn't the requirement be that if we don't want the String to be manipulated by all the threads at a time, then we should go for `StringBuffer`, otherwise it's fine to go for `StringBuilder`? What I am trying to understand is for a multi-threaded application why is it required to go for a synchronized implementation (if the requirement doesn't state that).

Comment: You are confusing 'synchronous' with 'synchronized'. It isn't the same thing. Where did you read this? It's extremely rare to have multiple threads working on the same string builder/buffer in the first place. Never done it in 25 years of Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Shouldn't the requirement be that if we don't want the String to be manipulated by all the threads at a time, then we should go for StringBuffer, otherwise it's fine to go for StringBuilder? What I am trying to understand is for a multi-threaded application why is it required to go for a synchronous implementation (if the requirement doesn't state that).

Yes.

Very few applications *actually* concurrently modify a character sequence, with the result that there's almost no reason to use `StringBuffer`.

Comment: You're correct: the "real world" likelihood two threads using StringBuilder at the same time is minimal.  Similarly, the "real world" performance increase choosing StringBuilder over StringBuffer is probably "minimal" at best.  My strong preference - for several different reasons - remains StringBuffer :)

Answer (score 2):

- [StringBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) has been around "forever".  It is thread safe.
- [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) is "newer" (first introduced in Java 1.5).
- [String](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) is immutable.  StringBuffer and StringBuilder are both mutable.  Using either StringBuffer or StringBuilder is *VASTLY* more efficient than modifying raw strings.

Per the documentation:

> https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html
>
> [StringBuilder] is mutable sequence of characters. This class provides
> an API compatible with StringBuffer, but with no guarantee of
> synchronization. This class is designed for use as a drop-in
> replacement for StringBuffer in places where the string buffer was
> being used by a single thread (as is generally the case). Where
> possible, it is recommended that this class be used in preference to
> StringBuffer as it will be faster under most implementations.

Personally, I always use StringBuffer in preference to manipulating raw String.  Mostly out of force of habit.

Yes, StringBuilder might be "faster". Or, in all likelihood, it will make little or no difference in overall "performance".

The key points to remember:

- Don't manipulate strings directly if you can use StringBuilder or StringBuffer instead.
- StringBuilder is non-synchronized (i.e. not thread safe). If two threads happen to use StringBuilder simultaneously, the results will be indeterminate.

You might also be interested in this:

> https://www.javatpoint.com/mutable-and-immutable-in-java
>
> **What are Mutable Objects?**
>
> The mutable objects are objects whose value can be changed after initialization. We can change the object's
> values, such as field and states, after the object is created. For
> example, Java.util.Date, StringBuilder, StringBuffer, etc.
>
> When we made a change in existing mutable objects, no new object will
> be created; instead, it will alter the value of the existing object.
> These object's classes provide methods to make changes in it.

Comment: Note that there are relatively few situations where multiple threads could meaningfully share a StringBuffer without requiring synchronization beyond what's built into that class.  If two threads perform simultaneous Append operations, and it's necessary that the result contain the appended strings interleaved in some arbitrary fashion, the synchronization supplied by StringBuffer may be sufficient, but most applications either wouldn't have two threads trying to perform simultaneous Append operations, or would have stronger requirements about the order in whcih strings are combined.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman - thank you for fixing my typo :)

Answer (score 1):

> I have read that if we have a multi-threaded application then it is better to go with StringBuffer. But if we have a single thread application then it’s better to go with StringBuilder.

This is a very simplistic answer to a usually complicated question.  The answer really should be that if multiple threads are *updating* the same string appender, you should use `StringBuffer`.  If you have two threads and each of them are using their own local string appender, then there is no need to pay for `StringBuffer` synchronization and `StringBuilder` can be used.  You should know that anytime you use the string `+` operator, a `StringBuilder` is being created under the covers.  But when it comes down to it, I've never seen the case of multiple threads sharing a string appender.

> But isn't the whole point of having a multi-threaded application is that simultaneously all the threads can work on the same piece of code?

No.  There are many reasons to write multi-threaded applications.  A web-server uses multiple threads so that web requests can be handled asynchronously and in parallel without necessarily sharing any code or data.

> Shouldn't the requirement be that if we don't want the String to be manipulated by all the threads at a time, then we should go for StringBuffer, otherwise it's fine to go for StringBuilder?

Not quite.  Don't think that `StringBuffer` stops multiple threads from manipulating the buffer.  Think that it *protects* the buffer from inappropriate access by multiple threads that would result in race-conditions and other unintended consequences.

> What I am trying to understand is for a multi-threaded application why is it required to go for a synchronized implementation

There is no such requirement *except* when multiple threads are *updating* an object.  If the threads are working on their own objects and never sharing them between threads, the no synchronization is required.  If multiple threads are updating an object (such as a shared `StringBuffer` then the `synchronized` keywords ensure that the changes are appropriately published between the threads and that the critical areas are protected by mutexes which insure only one thread can enter them at a time.

It is also important to realize that if Thread #1 creates (for example) a `HashMap` and then Thread #2 wants to use that `HashMap`, even if it is not updating it, then some sort of synchronization needs to happen to appropriately sync the *memory* between Thread #1 and #2.

`synchronization` enforces proper mutex locks so that critical code only has one thread working on it at a time and ensures appropriate memory publishing so that threads work on the latest version of an object as opposed to possibly stale versions in their local memory caches.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gray for such a detailed explanation for each point that I mentioned in the query.